# Integrate Mathquill into React Native by WebView

Tags: react-native

In WebView I added index.html

```
<WebView     
   source={{ uri: 'file:///android_asset/index.html' }}    
   startInLoadingState={true}    
   style={{ marginTop: 20, height: 100 }} />
```

In index.html file

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<header>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./mathquill.css" />
    <script src="./jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="./mathquill.js"></script>
    <script>
        var MQ = MathQuill.getInterface(2);
    </script>
</header>
<body>
        <span id="problem">ax^2 + bx + c = 0</span>
        <script>
          var problemSpan = document.getElementById('problem');
          MQ.StaticMath(problemSpan);
        </script>
</body>
</html>
```

I want know how to communicate with WebView to change the text to appear.

Answer (score 1):

Found solution.

add this to index.html

```
  document.addEventListener("message", function(data) {
     ...
  }
```

change WebView to

```
  <WebView 
    ref={(webview) => this.webview = webview }
    source={{ uri: 'file:///android_asset/index.html' }}
    startInLoadingState={true}
    style={{ marginTop: 20, height: 100 }}
  />
```

and to post data by (I tested in componentDidMount)

```
  componentDidMount() {
    this.webview.postMessage('message')
  }
```

Comment: Hi @Pansit 
is this approach worked for you, I am also looking for math equation editor for React Native. Please help here